# QT shared opengl context

Tags: qt, opengl, shared, openglcontext

I want multiple QGLWidgets to share a single context, I am not able to get this to work after creating a QGLWidget, binding a texture using bindTexture() and create a second QGLWidget with the same format as the first one and using one of the constructors that takes in the first widget as a pointer to the shared widget. It does create a new widget but textures are not shared and when I query using isShared() method I always get a false as a result.

Is there any simple example to tell me if I am doing the right thing!